# How to outline color an icon but that you can fill the color as well [Flutter]

Tags: android, flutter, dart, icons

Hi what I want to do is make a stacked Icons type similar to this example for Text:

```
Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    widget.news.title,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      foreground: Paint()
                        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
                        ..strokeWidth = 2
                        ..color = Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    widget.news.title,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

So what my goal is to have an amber colored fill with white outline for backarrow icon (added with SilverAppBar), but for now I was only able to access the iconTheme as follow:

```
iconTheme: IconThemeData(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
```

So my question is as follow: How can I have back arrow icon with SilverAppBar colored that way

Output Image:

[image: As you can see he text has a small outline around it I wish that Icon had it as well]

The Widget part code:

```
return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              pinned: true,
              expandedHeight: 200,
              title: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    widget.news.title,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      foreground: Paint()
                        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
                        ..strokeWidth = 2
                        ..color = Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    widget.news.title,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                background: Image.network(
                  widget.news.urlToImage,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  errorBuilder: (context, error, StackTrace) {
                    return Image(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image: AssetImage("images/placeholder_details.png"),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            )
          ];
```

Looking forward to hear your opinion :D

Comment: What do you get using Stack<ColoredBox,ICon>?

Comment: Hmm how would I implement that? Because Im also pretty new regarding flutter

Comment: I think you can replace the back button with a custom Widget.

Comment: Can you attach an output image?

Comment: I added the output image @YeasinSheikh

Comment: check SliverAppBar

Comment: What about SilverAppBar @YeasinSheikh

Comment: I think that will fill your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Tried out multiple solutions, and this works perfectly.

Use [icon_decoration](https://pub.dev/packages/icon_decoration) like this:

```
DecoratedIcon(
    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
    decoration: IconDecoration(border: IconBorder()),
)
```